# Ubuntu 23.04 aptX Adaptive Support

Tags: bluetooth, codecs

I have Haylou MoriPods headphones (with QCC3040 SoC) that support aptX Adaptive. My computer has Intel AX211 and this card supports Bluetooth 5.3. However, there is no option other than aptX, SBC, SBC-XQ. What should I do?